# AppWidget Imageview updatePeriodMillis

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appwidget

I am trying to have an ImageView in an AppWidget update every 30 minutes, but with no luck.

It uses the Glide library to load the widget, and I suspect caching.

I'm doing everything I can to prevent interferring with wake and the battery. Just needs to change the image every once and a while. On wake will be fine.

I'm thinking that 30 minute polling is when the device is active. Like, when it sleeps, it doesn't count and misses it.

Thank you for your help.

res/xml/widget_name.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget_name"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_name"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>
```

com/WidgetName/WidgetName.java

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_name);

        AppWidgetTarget awt = new AppWidgetTarget(context, R.id.imageView, remoteViews, appWidgetIds) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                super.onResourceReady(resource, transition);
            }
        };

        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().
                override(300, 300).placeholder(R.drawable.navigation_header_bg).error(R.drawable.ic_navigation_help);


        // Create an Intent to launch Browser
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetConfig.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Log.i("WidgetName", "src " + src);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent);
        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(src)
                .apply(options)
                .into(awt);

    }
```

Comment: where is your 'appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);' ?

Comment: nowhere !!! (?) https://github.com/urgent/lineameteo/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/LineaMeteoPremium/LineaMeteoPremium.java#L59

I'll pay you a bounty, and provide client introduction for free, if you can take this over the finish line. Let's talk!

Comment: okay .. i am looking into it..

Comment: Okay i Downloaded the project and looked into it and have requested a pull request on gihub. Don't forget to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taking look into your project you need to make following changes.

in res/xml/widget_name.xml set `android:updatePeriodMillis="0"`

Then in com/WidgetName/WidgetName.java

override onReceive method and make following changes

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE:
            onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, LineaMeteoPremium.class)));
            break;
        default:
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

And since you're updating all your widgets, updating them sequentially in a loop as follows with **AlarmManager** used as your refresh trigger (better flexibility as you can allow users to set custom refresh time too) and another issue was you were not using **skipMemoryCache(true)** and **diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)** methods to force glide to fetch new images instead of looking in cache.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        setUpAlarm(context, widgetId);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.linea_meteo_premium);

        Log.e("LineaMeteo Widget", "src " + src);

        AppWidgetTarget awt = new AppWidgetTarget(context, R.id.imageView, remoteViews, appWidgetIds);

        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().
                override(300, 300).placeholder(R.drawable.navigation_header_bg).error(R.drawable.ic_navigation_help).skipMemoryCache(true).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE);


        // Create an Intent to launch Browser
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetConfig.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);


        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent);

        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(src)
                .apply(options)
                .into(awt);
    }
}
```

Use the following code to set Alarm for refreshing widget based on the time you want

```
/**
 * Sets up widget refresh alarm
 *
 * @param context     The context of widget
 * @param appWidgetId Widget ID of current widget
 */
private void setUpAlarm(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long interval = (3 * 60000); // 60000 = 1minute  | Change the formula based on your refresh timing needs

    PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = getRefreshWidgetPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId);

    alarm.cancel(alarmPendingIntent);

    // SET NEW ALARM
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + interval, alarmPendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + interval, alarmPendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + interval, alarmPendingIntent);
    }
}

/**
 * Get the pending intent object for refreshing the widget
 *
 * @param context  current Context
 * @param widgetId - Current Widget ID
 * @return - Pending intent for refreshing widget
 */
private PendingIntent getRefreshWidgetPendingIntent(Context context, int widgetId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LineaMeteoPremium.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
    // Make the pending intent unique...
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

And most important, since your app is using ClearText HTTP Traffic and cleartext support is disabled by default beginning Android 9.0, you need to add the following tag in your manifest's appilcation Tag to prevent widget crashes on android 9.+ devices.

```
<application
.
.
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: Working! You are awesome. Thank you!